# Ordering by count with Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I want my search engine to be able to order Lawyers on the count of cases of a certain  case type. The most a lawyer has finalized cases of a certain type, the higher he will be ranked.

`lawyer.rb`

```
has_many :cases    
has_many :case_types, :through => :cases

define_index do
        indexes case_types.name, :as => :case_types
        has case_types(:id), :as => :case_types_id
        has "SUM(case_types)", :as => :case_type_count #this line gives an error,  as my lawyer table does't have a case_type column, also, I need to count DISTINCT case_types
      end
```

In my `search_controller.rb`, I would like to do something like that, suggestion being the name of a case type

```
@lawyers = Lawyer.search params[:suggestion], :order => "@case_type_count DESC"
```

Am I going the wrong way? should I think of a less Sphinx oriented method? The problem is I need to do an each_with_geodist on @lawyers, so I would need to get my lawyers through a Sphinx search.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your define_index:

```
has "COUNT(case_types.id)", :as => :case_type_count, :type => :integer

join case_types
```

Then retrieve by case_count:

```
Lawyer.search("", :order => "case_type_count desc")
```

I have found it useful to read the sql code in `development.sphinx.conf` which allows me to see the column names being generated.

Comment: Thanks! About to test this. What about the `join case_types` bit? What is it for? One more question : after reading the sphinx documentation for the  `:any` match mode, I came to the conclusion Sphinx would do this anyways since a lawyer having several cases of a certain type would yield more results. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually I am not sure this is the answer I needed. I need a Lawyer to be ranked higher on the number of cases OF A CERTAIN CASE TYPE he worked on, not on the total count of all case types. I think the case type must be a parameter of the search and can not be blank

Comment: Use "SUM(case_types.weight)" and add a weight column to the table for case_types

Comment: The join case_types sql joins your lawyer with case_types. You can change the sort order as described in http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html

Comment: What's the weight field for on case_types? I would need it to be different for each lawyer